# Published .NET 8 Application Includes Windows SDK for .NET 6

Tags: .net, runtime, publish, .net-8.0

When I publish a WPF application using VS 2022 and targeting .NET 8 in the publish folder Microsoft.Windows.SDK.NET.dll is Windows SDK for .NET 6.

In my project file as well as the UI, Target Framework is set to .NET 8:

```
<TargetFramework>net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>
```

[image]

In Visual Studio Installer I confirmed .NET 8 Runtime is included:

[image]

Is this expected? Are released .NET 8 applications actually using .NET 6 SDK or is there something wrong with how I have the project configured or published?